# How do I upload my reformatted image?

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, image-resizing

I know this is very close to complete.
My aim is to re-size the image a user is uploading by a factor of 0.5.
I have achieved in returning the width and height of the image uploaded and have achieved halving those values. Code below:

```
//get image attributes
    $target = "Images/";
    $target = $target . basename($_FILES['myFile']['name']);

    $thumbnailsize = 0.5;

    //Get uploaded image width and height.
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($target);

    //Half the current image in size.
    $newWidth = $width * $thumbnailsize;
    $newheight = $height * $thumbnailsize;

    $new_target = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    $image = imagecreate($newWidth, $newheight);

    imagecopyresized($image, $new_target, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    $pic = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'], $target);
```

I think I am now going wrong with my variable use and UPDATE SQL statement, see below:

```
$tUser_SQLselect = "UPDATE User SET imageLocation='" . $pic . "' ";
$tUser_SQLselect .= "WHERE ID = '" . $userID . "' ";
```

Any advice will appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling `imagejpeg()` in there anywhere, so your resized file is not saved anywhere. And unless you're planning on saving the original file alongside the resized one, you cannot use move_uploaded_files() on the copy - m_u_l() exists specifically to apply certain security checks on the uploaded files, so no tampering can occur after the upload completes but before the file's moving around - your resized image would trigger the safety check.

You are also wide-open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) via that `$pic` variable - the `['name']` parameter in the $_FILES array is user-supplied data, and can be used to subvert your server.